# remove internet access for a single tool or process

Tags: networking, ubuntu, process, internet-connection, blocking

I need to ban a local running tool or a process (or PID) from the internet  into the "localhost"-world only, because it should not talk to the internet but should be available/accessible on localhost.

I searched the internet and found something like unshare, to remove the whole network access (but localhost is needed) or iptables, if the process is running in an dedicate user context (in order to block internet access for the user, which is not my goal).

Is there a way to remove, for example, only the access to the wired network interface and keep access to the 'lo' Interface?
I use ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is in the realm of firewall entries, really.  Are you writing this software, or is it something pre-made that you're trying to limit?

Comment: Network namespaces? See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96375/171560)

Comment: @CDove I'm using an existing Software: geth, which tries to connect to different webservices, although it runs in "localhost" mode.